# Should I encapsulate an object inside another object as methods or just access it directly?

Tags: object-oriented, class-design, class, composition

Suppose I have a class A:

```
public class A{
    public void a(){
    }
}
```

and class B use A:

```
public class B{
    private A a;
}
```

Should I encapsulate A in B:

```
public class B{
    private A a;
    public void a(){
        a.a();
    }
}
```

then

```
new B().a();
```

or just let users of B access A directly:

```
public class B{
    private A a;
    public A getA(){
        return A;
    }
}
```

then

```
new B().getA().a();
```

?

I believe many people prefer new B().a(); because it allows users of B doesn't need to know about A. But I found it has at least one disadvantage: if I add new methods in A, I need to modify both A and B, while if I just let users access A directly, then I don't need to modify B and just:

```
new B().getA().a();
new B().getA().newMethod();
```

Should encapsulate A in B as methods?Or just let users of B access A directly?

Comment: Is there any piece of real code you can share for contextualizing the question? I think giving us a little more context of your actual model you could get more precise answers

Comment: _If I add new methods in A, I need to modify both A and B_: this looks like inheritance.

Comment: Delegation pattern is a sort of inheritance. Problem is that with the given examples we don't know if OP is Implementing: Inheritance, composition, delegation. Here the context matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid **both**. They are both smells on their own right (at least in the way described).

The **first option** (as described) is a smell if (and only *if*) it's really necessary to replicate all methods that `A` exposes in `B`. Class `B` should exist to do something. If `B` replicates the public interface of `A` (*without implementing the same interface*) it seems to me, that `B` does not really do anything (or it does what it does *and* exposes the interface to `A` - i.e. `B` does more than one thing, which is a smell itself). Anyway, if both `A` and `B` derive from the same base class or interface it's another story. `B` could be a decorator implementing additional functionality. An example would be logging the calls to `A.a()`. `B.a()` could emit a log-message, call `A.a()` and then emit another log-message.

The **second option** (exposing `B.a` publicly) is considered a bad idea by many people. Anyway, there *are* exceptions. It may be considered okay, if `A` is a mere data class (but not necessarily).

In either case it's considered cleaner if `B` provides its own public interface  that operates on `A` somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The [Law of Demeter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) says you should use version 1.  Many of us prefer to call it "suggestion of Demeter

[Don't_repeat_yourself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), general LEAN guidelines, say use version 2 so when you add a new method to A you only have to add in once, not again in B (and C, D...)  The nice thing about software principles is that you have many to choose from.  :-(

**My view: It Depends**

If A is an abstract, robust, well understood class, such as a List or a Stream, use version 2 and let users connect directly.  They **already know** the interface to A, you gain nothing by hiding it.  Be practical.

But if A is some complex messy, beta home built class of your own, limit access using the Law of Demeter.

Comment: If `A` is a (mutable) `List`, it is probably not a good idea to expose it directly. I would prefer exposing an immutable view on the List (or a `Stream` as you suggested).

Comment: @Hulk Noted.  Alternatively, treat all Lists that you get from somewhere else as immutable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule.  In *general* we would encapsulate `A` behind `B`, only exposing functionality and data as needed, and as makes sense in the context of what `B` is.

That's in *general*.

In practice, I'm sure there are plenty of examples where an object `Foo` is composed of an object `Bar` and the **pragmatic** solution is to merely expose `Bar` as a `public` member.  But that decision would need to be made on a case-by-case basis as it depends on a lot of things.

This ultimately boils down to a modeling question.  So, depending on what your `Foo` (or `B`) is modeling, you'll have different answers.

TLDR: Encapsulation is a great **guideline** but don't forget to be pragmatic.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine writing the documentation for `B`. If `A` can be referred naturally and directly in that documentation(other than the part about construction) you should use the second option. If the documentation will only refer to `A` implementation detail("*behind the scenes it uses `A` to...*") then you should use the first option.

For example, let's say `A` is `Person` and `B` is `Depratment`. The documentation can say that a department has a manager - that's not an internal implementation detail, that's part of the `Department` official and external definition! So, we don't want to see code like `department.getManagerName()`: the department does not have just have a manager name - the entire manager object is part of the API - so we should have `department.getManager().getName()`. This means we can also do things like `vacation.addParticipant(department.getManager())`, which would look awkward with the first approach(`department.sendManagerToVacation(vacation)` ugh...).

Different example - let's say `A` is `TCPConnection` and `B` is `FooReader` which reads encoded `Foo`s from the TCP connection to create `Foo` object. How will the `FooReader` documentation refer to the `TCPConnection`? Probably as an implementation detail("*`FooReader` reads from a `TCPConnection`*") or when it talks about construction("*Use `new FooReader(tcpConnection)` to read `Foo`s from a TCP connection*"). The TCP connection is not part of the `Foo` reader API - if you get a `FooReader` object all you need to know is that it reads `Foo`s - you don't care where it reads them from. Therefore we use the first option here, and use, for example, `fooStream.hasMore()` instead of `fooStream.getTcpConnection().hasMore()`. The user don't care if the TCP connection has more values - it only cares whether or not there are more `Foo`s to read.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the purpose of B?**

**Is B a Decorator that mimics all A methods but does nothing but add some functionality to A without having to change it?**

It is not clear in your question because A and B doesn't seem to implement the same interface which is a requirement of the decorator pattern. But if it is so, then option 1 is a very valid option.

**Is A just a dependency injected to B to be delegated some specific function?**

In such case B would'nt usually wrap every method in A, but just make a call to a couple of A methods, usually internally. It's another form of changing B's functionality without actually changing the code.

**Is A just a member of B?**

In that case you have to be careful of using option 2 because the consumer could change A's state. Is that what you want? Will B be used in multiple threads? (if so you would need extra considerations).

**As you can see there are more reasons to encapsulate A than to expose it.**

Also there are some principles against option 2 like the [Law of Demeter (also called the Principle of Less Knowledge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), the very notion of encapsulation, an antipattern called [Train Wreck](http://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck).

**Law of Demeter of Principle of less knowledge:**

> 1. Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> 2. Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> 3. Only talk to your immediate friends.

**Train Wreck antipattern:**

> The train wreck anti pattern occurs when a series of method calls are
>   appended to one another all in one line of code. If you find yourself
>   spending a lot of time reading through a series of method calls and
>   trying to figure out what the line of code is actually doing, you
>   probably are dealing with a train wreck.